# Obtaining different CDF of non-standard normal distribution using two methods

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

I was reading about the derivation of the CDF of a non-standard normal distribution.

One particular version goes like this:

Let $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2), Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1).$

$\therefore X = \sigma Z + \mu$

$$
P(X\le x) = P\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} \le \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right) = \Phi\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)
$$

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9vp1Ll2NpRw&t=14m54s (Harvard stats 110)

Now, I thought of another variation, this time arriving at a different conclusion:

$$
P(X\le x) = P\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} \le \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right) = P(Z\le z)
$$

My version looks grossly incorrect. How could the CDF of $X$ and $Z$ be the same? Could someone please advise me on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

They're not the same because $z$ isn't $x$, but rather is $(x-\mu)/\sigma$.

Comment: Yeah. I understand that the CDFs ought to be different. But I cannot understand why I managed to derive an equality between them in my working (which I think is mathematically correct). Did I intepret my own conclusion wrongly?

Comment: @LanceHAOH You've shown a function of $x$ is equal to a function of $z$, with $z$ being some function of $x$ other than the identity function. But the functions aren't "the same" in the sense of returning the same output for a given shared input. It's like how $f(y):=y^9,\,g(y):=y^3\implies f(y)=g(y^3)$.

Comment: Ok. I understand your example($f \neq g$ although their values are equal given different inputs). The thing that is confusing me is this thought: "CDF of $X$ = $P(X \le x)$ = $P(Z \le z)$ = CDF of $Z$". I am not sure whether my example is valid though. Would you mind helping to clarify this?

Comment: @LanceHAOH Since $X\le x$ is equivalent to $Z\le z$ for $z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$, the two conditions indeed have equal probabilities. But $X,\,Z$ have different CDFs because e.g. $P(X\le 1)\ne P(Z\le 1)$.

Comment: Ah, ok, understood, so in my verson of the working, the CDFs are actually not the same. But due to different inputs, their outputs are the same. Did I get that right?

Comment: @LanceHAOH That's exactly right. What's more, this isn't a unique characteristic of linear transformations among Normal distributions; you could pull the same trick with any order-preserving transformation of any probability distribution.

Answer (score 1):

In their working $\Phi$ is CDF of $Z$.

In your working, you did not define what is $z$. I believe you want to define $z$ such that $z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}.$

We have $$P(X \le x) =P(Z \le z)= P(Z \le \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}).$$

Nothing wrong about that.

Comment: "you did not define what is $z$" Hmm. $z$ is just the output of the function $Z$ right? Since $Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$, shouldn't $z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$ where $x$ is the output of the function $X$?

Comment: $z$ is just a symbol of which I can guess the intended meaning. You might let to include a linear let $z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$ explicitly. Simply because you have defined $Z$, it doesn't mean that $z$ has been defined.

Comment: Ah. Ok. So an explicit definition was what I was missing. I will be sure to include it next time. Thanks!